# Excel VBA Marco Rows(...).Select selecting too many rows

Tags: excel, ssrs-2012, vba

I have the following macro:

```
1. Columns("A:A").Select
2. Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
3. Rows("1:10").Select
4. Selection.RowHeight = 14.25
5. Rows("2:3").Select
```

However the code at line 5 selects rows 1-5 instead of rows 2 and 3 any ideas why this would be?

The file is exported from a SSRS Report and I am just trying to write a macro that would clean up the formatting because it merges cells. Is there something unknown to me that is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cells are merged across rows, then it might not be possible to select the rows you want. If there is one cell that is merged from row 1 to 5, then selecting rows 2 to 3 would select 1 to 5. That's why merged cells are bad.

Unmerge all cells in rows 1 to 5 before attempting to select rows 2 and 3.

Comment: Yeah I should of thought of that. I was recording the same macro about 5 times and I must have done it in the reverse order. Thanks